# Breakpoint is not hitting in WCF service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, debugging

I am running WCF service and Winform client in same solution and both are setup as startup project in solution properties.

In my client application, I am sending a request to WCF service to varify user credentials/permissions. I setup a breakpoint in WCF service for this but the strange issue is, this breakpoint is never hit. Although, If I try usinf F11 from client code (as both project in same solution) it give me "No Source Available" Error.

Below is source file information from No source available screen...

```
Locating source for 'c:\BuildAgent\work\8689a06309d1ab0b\src\Castle.Core\DynamicProxy\Internal\CompositionInvocation.cs'. Checksum: MD5 {58 4e d2 46 37 96 c8 96 ae 5e 6b 8c ca f5 36 33}
The file 'c:\BuildAgent\work\8689a06309d1ab0b\src\Castle.Core\DynamicProxy\Internal\CompositionInvocation.cs' does not exist.
Looking in script documents for 'c:\BuildAgent\work\8689a06309d1ab0b\src\Castle.Core\DynamicProxy\Internal\CompositionInvocation.cs'...
Looking in the projects for 'c:\BuildAgent\work\8689a06309d1ab0b\src\Castle.Core\DynamicProxy\Internal\CompositionInvocation.cs'.
The file was not found in a project.
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\crt\src\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\src\mfc\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\src\atl\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\include\'...
The debug source files settings for the active solution indicate that the debugger will not ask the user to find the file: c:\BuildAgent\work\8689a06309d1ab0b\src\Castle.Core\DynamicProxy\Internal\CompositionInvocation.cs.
The debugger could not locate the source file 'c:\BuildAgent\work\8689a06309d1ab0b\src\Castle.Core\DynamicProxy\Internal\CompositionInvocation.cs'.
```

From this error msg, I can see it is referrning some c:\BuildAgent\work\ path but how it is picking this path. My source code not at all on this location.

Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If your WCF service is not self-hosted you need to attached the process on w3wp upon debugging for you to hit that breakpoint you set.

If you'are not seeing w3wp.exe try to check *Show processes from all users*.

Comment: I am using self hosting and can see service is running without any issue. I can also request the data from the service without any issue. The issue comes only when i try to debug the service.

Comment: I'm not quite sure but have you tried to attached the process to your running self-hosted wcf service?

Comment: How did you reference your service in your client?

Comment: Can you add a bit of your client code including on how you created your channelFactory? And if possible can you include on how you host your service.

Answer (score 0):

Go to  **Debug**--->**Attach to Process** -->Select **w3wp.exe** and click **Attach** button:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am using self hosting and can see service is running without any issue. I can also request the data from the service without any issue. The issue comes only when i try to debug the service.

So W3wp is not application in my case.